# How to create a timer loop which will work after page refreshing?

Tags: javascript, loops, timer, countdown, infinite

I have created my own countdown and it seems that I'm missing a part, whenever I refresh the page it also refresh the timer itself. I am looking to maximize the performance with that script so how can I make it looping infinitely?

**Here is the code:**

```
function startGRBTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    hours, minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    days = parseInt(timer / (24 * 60 * 60), 10);
    hours = parseInt(timer % (24 * 60 * 60) / (60 * 60), 10);
    minutes = parseInt(timer % (60 * 60) / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display.textContent = days + "d" + " " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s";
    --timer;
    if (timer <= 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

var display = document.querySelector("#grb");
startGRBTimer(60, display);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just the way this code works, there is nothing wrong with it. Every time you refresh the page, the script gets re-run, and the `var timer =  duration, hours, minutes, seconds;` is created whenever the page is loaded.

You should look into creating first, and then storing the variable to the user's local storage, and have your program read the info from that variable (or array).

Comment: So which way is the best to do that and keep performance at best?

Comment: Look into the localstorage object, do a search for it.

Comment: I mean, in the code itself (I'm pretty much learning JS atm), where would be the best to add a localstorage and how at his max potential?

Comment: After you read the basic concept of how that works (mdn web docs are amazingly well written) you will have to store your time (remaining time or elapsed) into a variable periodically. This you can do with a set interval, or detect on page close.

Comment: I'm really interested in using a setInterval tho! I'm just not sure how to implement it correctly yet :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some job independently from your web application, with ability to live after page refresh, right?

It's highly likely that [ServiceWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

We could "misuse" **[`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)** (see documentation link) for this case like in following example. Or you could use **[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**, but this does not work for local files (`file:///...`). And because of this `window.name` is better and shorter too.

**Solution**

```js
function startGRBTimer(duration, display)
{
    var timer = window.name == '' ? duration : window.name,
        hours, minutes, seconds;

    setInterval(function()
    {
        days = parseInt(timer / (24 * 60 * 60), 10);
        hours = parseInt(timer % (24 * 60 * 60) / (60 * 60), 10);
        minutes = parseInt(timer % (60 * 60) / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        display.textContent = days + "d" + " " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s";
        --timer;

        if(timer <= 0)
        {
            timer = duration;
        }

        window.name = timer;
    }, 1000);
}

var display = document.querySelector("#grb");
startGRBTimer(60, display);
```

```html
<div id="grb"></div>
```